# Cucumber Runner Class not running Step Definitons

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am writing automated tests with Cucumber and Java.

I can run the step definitions by right-clicking on my Feature file, and running it as a Cucumber Feature, and all steps pass successfully.

But, I need to run them using a Runner Class.

My feature file is in this folder:

> src/test/java/features

And my step definitons are in this folder:

> src\test\java\com\abc\commercial\def\automation

My Runner Class is also stored in

> src\test\java\com\abc\commercial\def\automation

And here is the Runner Class code:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"progress",
            "html:build/report/html",
            "junit:build/report/junit/cucumber-report.xml",
            "json:build/report/json/cucumber-report.json"
    },
    glue = {"src\\test\\java\\com\\abc\\commercial\\def\\automation"},
    features = {"src/test/java/features"}
    )
public class QARunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When I run the Runner Class as a JUnit Test, I receive the following response in the console:

```
UUUUUUUUU

Undefined scenarios:
src/test/java/features/US46052
src/test/java/features/postFeatures.feature:43 # As the

2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
9 Steps (9 undefined)
0m0.303s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("the Application...")
public void the_Application...() {
```

So the step definitions are not being picked up.

Does it have something to do with where my test runner is located?
I don't think it is picking up the step definitons in the *automation* folder

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : No need for main method. `glue` option should be in package style.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"progress",
            "html:build/report/html",
            "junit:build/report/junit/cucumber-report.xml",
            "json:build/report/json/cucumber-report.json"
    },
    glue = {"com.abc.commercial.def.automation"},
    features = {"src/test/java/features"}
    )
public class QARunner {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes the Runner Class run as JUnit pass. But, I need to run the Runner Class as _Gradle test_ now. When I leave the main method in the class, the Gradle Test runs with no errors. But, when I look at the test reports in the target folder, no tests have been run?

Comment: I do not have any idea about gradle with cucumber